# Trying to Edit 'Blog' Template, to display full posts not excerpts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with a theme I paid for a long time ago, customized a bunch graphically and with the CSS and am pulling pieces of it into separate directory via iFrame Fancybox.

BUT, I'm trying to reformat the blog template - as currently it renders and populates when updated as:

Title
*etc etc*
A few lines of Content here/ then cuts of mid sentence.
*Read More* , etc // And these links just refresh the page?

**So, I'm a bit novice with PHP & am wondering how I'd edit the below 'Blog Template' code to allow full posts text to display, not excerpts that are cut off in the middle:**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog Template
*/
get_header();
?>          
            <div id="content">

                <?php 
                    //get exclusions for categories
                    $exclude = get_option($shortname.'_exclude_categories');                
                    $exclude = str_replace(',,','|-',$exclude);
                    $exclude = str_replace(',','-',$exclude);
                    $exclude = substr($exclude, 0, -1);
                    $exclude = str_replace('|',',',$exclude);

                    query_posts('posts_per_page=&paged='.$paged.'&cat='.$exclude); 
                    if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                ?>      

                <div class="entry" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    <p class="meta">Added by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?> on <a href="<?php echo get_month_link($get_year, $get_month); ?>"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></a>, filed under <?php the_category(', ') ?></p>

                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <p><?php the_post_thumbnail('wide'); ?></p>
                        <?php the_excerpt('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
                        <p><?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">~ Add your thoughts</a> | <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Continue Reading</a></p>
                    </div><!-- e: entry content -->
                </div><!-- e: entry -->

                <?php 
                    endwhile; 
                    //endif;
                ?>

                <div class="paginate">
                    <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } ?>   
                </div>

                <?php else : ?>

                <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
                <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </div><!-- e: content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the_excerpt() with the_content(), that's it.